# Typescript switch statement executes false case?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

If have [Stackblitz: the following typescript switch block](https://stackblitz.com/edit/todo-combinelatests-test?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftodo.service.ts) and it executes the first case, even though the filter is false (Shown with logging statements below):

```
  public applyFilter(filter, completeTodos, incompleteTodos): Todo[] {
    console.log("FILTER VALUE: ", filter);
      console.log("IS THE FILTER TRUE?", filter == true);
    switch (filter) {
      case filter == true:
        console.log("Returning complete TODOS");
        return completeTodos;
        break;
      case filter == false:
        console.log("Returning incomplete TODOS");
        return incompleteTodos;
        break;
      default:
        console.log("Returning the Default");
        return completeTodos;
    }
  }
```

This is what the console logs (Can be seen in stackblitz link):

```
FILTER VALUE:
false
IS THE FILTER TRUE?
false
Returning complete TODOS
```

I have a feeling I'm missing something really simple, but at the same time this just seems wrong ... Thoughts?

Comment: Try `case true:` and `case false:`.

Comment: `filter` is false, so it's going to the first `case` that evaluates to `false`, which is `filter == true`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not how you write switch cases. The whole idea is to switch on a dynamic value and then let each case handle a static value.

```
switch (filter) {
  case true:
    console.log("Returning complete TODOS");
    return completeTodos;
  case false:
    console.log("Returning incomplete TODOS");
    return incompleteTodos;
  default:
    console.log("Returning the Default");
    return completeTodos;
}
```

The `break` statements are redundant too since you return before them. You only need `break` if you want to continue execution after the switch block.

Also, your default case is kinda moot since a bool is either true or false, unless you plan to pass `undefined` in some case.

Comment: @DavidAnthonyAcosta I'm with you. A "switch statement for booleans" is otherwise just called "an if statement"

Comment: `break` is not required.

Comment: Yeah I'll remove the breaks as well. Just copied the code from the question.

Comment: Indeed - I am having a problem with a more elaborate setup, so I tried to boil it down to the bare minimum ... The real use case would use an Enum and check whether the filter is an Enum value.

Comment: @Ole then use the bog standard way of switching enums `switch(someVar)` and then have `case VALUE_ONE`, `case VALUE_TWO`, `case VALUE_THREE` etc.

Comment: OK - Very cool!  I can Switch now!!  The Stackblitz has the new code, in case anyone looks at it and gets confused....

Comment: Great! If you are satisfied with the answer you can accept it by clicking the checkmark under the vote buttons.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of a switch is to use the value within the `switch(someValue)` and check it within each case, but you're manually doing each case checking.

If you wish to keep it this way, put true in the `switch(true)`

```js
const filter = false;

switch (true) {
  case filter == true:
    console.log("Returning complete TODOS");
    break;
  case filter == false:
    console.log("Returning incomplete TODOS");
    break;
  default:
    console.log("Returning the Default");
}
```

Otherwise, use the switch statement like so:

```js
const filter = false;

switch (filter) {
  case true:
    console.log("Returning complete TODOS");
    break;
  case false:
    console.log("Returning incomplete TODOS");
    break;
  default:
    console.log("Returning the Default");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Refer](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) how switch case work:

This is how it works:

The switch expression is evaluated once.
The value of the expression is compared with the values of each case.
If there is a match, the associated block of code is executed.

Your case **filter == true** is returning **false**

Change your code like this:

```
public applyFilter(filter, completeTodos, incompleteTodos): Todo[] {
    console.log("FILTER VALUE: ", filter);
    console.log("IS THE FILTER TRUE?", filter == true);
    switch (filter) {
      case true:
        console.log("Returning complete TODOS");
        return completeTodos;
        break;
      case false:
        console.log("Returning incomplete TODOS");
        return incompleteTodos;
        break;
      default:
        console.log("Returning the Default");
    return completeTodos;
    }
  }
```